# Simpler array declaration syntax in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

In the spirit of Go-language, where simpler syntax is considered pretty important, here's a proposal for simpler array declaration in C++:

```
int   value;
int_1 list;
int_2 table;
int_3 cube;
RECT  rect;
RECT_1 rects;
```

Using typedefs this can expand to:

```
int   value;
vector<int> list;
vector<vector<int> > table;
vector<vector<vector<int> > > cube;
RECT  rect;
vector<RECT> rects;
```

Would you use it, or is there such a thing as too simple syntax?

**EDIT:** 
there was a mistake in expansion syntax.. fixed `vector< int>` to `vector< vector< int> >`..

Comment: Why is this simpler? In any case the place to post suggestions for changes to C++ is the usenet group comp.std.c++ - at http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++

Comment: If you want to go real with C++ changes, go to the newsgroup `comp.std.c++`.  Without deep background knowledge nothing reasonable will come up.  And no, I would not use it.  I do not use C++ for its simple syntax, BTW.

Comment: Discussing language design is a good practice for a programmer. comp.std.c++ might not be the best place to start discussing C++ for a beginner.

Comment: @Neil: sorry, there was mistake in expansion syntax (see Edit). Does it make more sence now?

Comment: C++0x will allow template typedef's which allow you to achieve things like `Vector<int, 3> cube; Vector<RECT, 2> table` where Vector is a typedef for an appropriate kind of vector. - Your suggestion is very raw (`_` is a valid character in tokens, you'd need completely new syntax), and probably too inflexible.

Comment: "inflexible" in one project is "all you'll ever need" in another. I'm currently programming one project that is heavily relying on arrays (using hundreds of them). There this syntax is irreplaceable, and all the c++0x extensions are YAGNI.

Comment: So make a file where all these things are typedeffed, or add those typedefs to all declarations of types? (It's unreasonable to expect that "int_1" will ever be interpreted as more than one token. BTW, Go doesn't seem to have anything like it either?)

Comment: Sure typedefing those int_x types is pretty straightforward if all your arrays use the same template (like std::vector). And no, Go doesnt have things like this, but it uses pretty minimalistic syntax for public/private declarations (Public members names start with capital letter, private ones with lower cased letter), which is also pretty outrageous at the first glance :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be straightforward if they didn't use the same type (apart from the confusion for users)? Python also uses a similar idea (names beginning with underscores are mangled, so "private" in a sense or so). But as a change proposition this is rather futile, since nobody is going to accept changes this fundamental (has endless potential for breaking existing code, because RECT_1 etc are all valid identifier names).

Comment: Yeah, confusion is the biggest problem there. Might be too difficult to define which templates are used where. Easier just peek one for the whole program. And, yes, these kind of changes are not possible in c++ language, it's just too different of a monster.

Comment: this is a hypothetical question, which is not allowed per http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: That's why suggested moving it to programmers.stackexchange.com, not closing it >:-/

Answer (score 2):

Names carry semantics, nothing else does. `int_1` doesn't convey a lot in terms of meaning, whereas `vector< int >` is quite clear here.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that a simpler syntax is welcome, specifically in C++ where control characters (dots, brackets, parenthesis, semi-columns) often introduce graphical noise in the code.

But why use numbers in order to identify an array? Is this the array size? In this case, a `vector<int>` might not be appropriate...

I would go with something simpler like `intArray`. But again, you have to balance between the benefits and the WTF-effect when a programmer will see this.

**EDIT**: Wow, based on your edit, looks like the number means the dimension. It might be a little trickier than simply using a typedef since multi-dimensions array have difficult semantics. You to have initialize your array dimension by dimension whenever needed.

When is actually the hardest part, it might be simpler to initialize everything at the beginning but large data may force you to initialize dimensions as you go.

Comment: You mean noise like the '+' and '=' signs in a = b + c?

Comment: Yes and no. Your example is perfectly clear and does not carry noise. I meant noise comparing C++ "object.doSomething();" compared to Ruby "object.do_something". I was referring to graphical noise if you see what I mean. Operators might not be the right word I agree. Editing.

Comment: "multi-dimensions array have difficult semantics" - yes, it might take page or few of simple typedef-listings, and some amount of manual work to upkeep it :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't.

How is this simpler exactly?

Also, the syntax for arrays in C++ is:

```
int   value;
int list[1];
int table[2];
int cube[3];
RECT  rect;
RECT rects[1];
```

Not sure it that was the intention of your blurb since I don't see the sense in a 1 cell array.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in expansion syntax.. fixed vector< int> to vector< vector< int> >..

Comment: @shoosh, i believe "list" is thought as  int[], and "table" is thought as "int[][]" and cube is "int[][][]". Of course, these types are invalid in C++ currently.

Comment: no but `int x[3][4][5]` certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use it. Maybe if you did macro's that would expand to tuples instead:

```
_(int, int) int_pair; // tr1::tuple<int, int>
_(int, int, int) coord_3d; // tr1::tuple<int, int, int>
```

If you don't like `_` as a macro then you might want to look at using something less often used.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of vector for an array would seem somewhat strange. Why not `std::(tr1::)array`?

But how about something like that:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T, size_t N>
struct Nested
{
    typedef std::vector< typename Nested<T, N - 1>::type > type;
};

template <class T>
struct Nested<T, 0u>
{
    typedef T type;
};


int main()
{
    Nested<int, 2>::type table;
    table.push_back(Nested<int, 1>::type());
    table.front().push_back(10);
}
```

For the lack of template typedefs until C++0x where you could add:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
using NestedVector = typename Nested<T, N>::type

//usage:
NestedVector<int, 3> vec; //vector<vector<vector<int>>>
```

Comment: Actually vector<x> was more of a pseudocode.. I'm not saying it should be std::vector :)